# update UITableVIewCell subView in autolayer

Tags: ios, uitableview

My English is very poor, please forgive me
,l use the storyboard and auto layer。

I want to achieve chat View，I met the first question is ，When I want to change the size of the button。

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Mq4.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wySdr.png]

help~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

All rows have the same height, you should use auto layout and make the tableView has dynamic row height.

Then height of label will increase according to its text length. If you use button to display text, I assume you have set its titleLabel to be like this.

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

I have done a test, setting text for titleLabel failed to make the cell height dynamic, while if I use a label instead of a button, it did give me the right result, so I suggest you make  the button behind the label if you really need it, and make its frame to the same as the label's.

Comment: hello,Thank you,I now say, is translation, there may be some translation is not good, please forgive me.I now is under the way of autolayer hope, manually in the code, change his size. I hope you can give some advice

Comment: Hi, what you want to achieve? Changing the button size so that text will fit?

Comment: yes, Is actually I set up his constraints, the use of a third party to add constraints of auxiliary class. But no effect. I hope you can give some advice, or example. Thank you very much.

Comment: And I use a storyboard